# How to decode string when using data-bind

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I have meet with a problem.

In my view I use a span to bind my string.

```
<span data-bind="text: myString"></span>
```

In the model:
`myString = '<b>I want Show in Bold!</b>'`;

It always show the origin string in my view.So how to make the view know it is a HTML tag?

Comment: change `text` to `html` `<span data-bind="html: myString"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

Use html binding as per [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html)

```
<span data-bind="html: myString"></span>
```